# c# Predicate with no parameters

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, func

I'm trying to pass a Predicate to a function but it has no input. I'm actually trying to delay the computation until the call is made.

Is there a way to use c# Predicate type for that? If not why.

I know a way to do this with Func

```
Func<bool> predicate = () => someConditionBool;
```

But I want to do this:

```
Predicate<> predicate = () => someConditionBool;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `Func<bool>` is the correct type.

Comment: Predicate delegate requires one argument. You provide 0 arguments. So just use Func<bool> - that's perfectly fine. Of course if you like the name - you can define your own predicate: `public delegate bool Predicate();`

Comment: Can you please explain what's wrong with `Func<bool>`? It's not clear what *problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: `Predicate` is just a synonym for `Func<T,bool>`

Comment: I see it more readable using Predicate when it's a predicate. No logic behind it.

Comment: You might declare your own predicate as shown in my above comment (I've edited it so you might have missed it).

Comment: Going against existing naming conventions isn’t really a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's just a readability problem, then you can create your own delegate which returns boolean and don't have any parameters:

```
public delegate bool Predicate();
```

And use it this way

```
Predicate predicate = () => someConditionBool;
```

NOTE: You should keep in mind that everyone is familiar with default `Action` and `Func` delegates which are used in .NET, but `Predicate` is your custom delegate and it will be less clear at first time for average programmer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use c# Predicate type for that? If not why?

Looking at the signature of [`Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) is shows that it requires an argument or parameter:

> ```
> public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj)
> ```

So the quick answer here would be no. Because you have no parameters in your anonymous function.

But if you play a little around you can give the predicate some irrelevant object which it will not use anyway, like an alibi parameter:

```
Func<bool> predicate = () => 1 == 1;
Predicate<object> predicate2 = (x) => 1 == 1;
```

and the call would look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(predicate());
Console.WriteLine(predicate2(null));
```

And this compiles and returns the correct result